# Trim slocate results. Find all instances of a specific directory

Tags: shell, replace, sed

I want to find all instances of directory `../foobar/` scattered on my system. This directory may contain hundreds of files/folders below it, which I don't care about. `$ slocate  "/foobar/"` may return 1000's of results, finding every full-pathname that includes "/foobar/". I only want the eg. 4 locations of the foobar/ folder.

How can I truncate the output of `slocate` at a given directory level and only show one line for each instance of the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

Use **slocate**, then **sed** to truncate each result and finally **uniq -c**.

```
$ slocate "foobar/" | sed 's/\/foobar\/.*/\/foobar\//' | uniq -c
```

#### Improved:

Using a local-variable. This iteration also handles search-terms with a space " ".
(see ex. 2)

```
$ LOOK="bazbar"
$ slocate "$LOOK"/ |sed "s/${LOOK}\/.*/${LOOK}\//" | uniq -c
```

---

### Explanation:

`sed` syntax will be familiar if you use VIM. The important part is using `.*` to pattern-match to the end of the line. Simplified this is `s/foobar.*/foo/` . When including the directory slashes /foobar/ one must then escape them using a backslash `\`.

We've truncated each line of slocate's output, but not the number of lines returned.

`uniq -c` drops all redundant lines. The optional -c flag prepends each printed result with the number of duplicate occurrences slocate originally returned. In this case, indicating how many files are contained under the directory.

### Examples:

#### Example 1

```
slocate "resume/" | sed 's/\/resume\/.*/\/resume\//g' | uniq -c 
  22 /dpool/data/2008-2010/documents/resume/
 621 /dpool/data/documents/resume/
 141 /dpool/data/2001-2007/documents/resume/
  35 /dpool/data/2001-2007/portfolio/resume/
```

#### Example 2

Improved to use a variable and handle spaces. Adding `| head` helps verify the output will be as expected.

```
$ LOOK="Current H-Drive Backup"
$ slocate "$LOOK"/ |sed "s/${LOOK}\/.*/${LOOK}\//" | uniq | head

/dpool/backup/2011/Current H-Drive Backup/
/dpool/backup/2012/Current H-Drive Backup/
/dpool/data/avalon2010/college/Current H-Drive Backup/
/dpool/data/avalon2010/windows_docs/Current H-Drive Backup/
```

*Notes: Tested on OpenSolaris with BASH shell.*

Comment: Biased towards my own answer. Specifically wanted this for a while and had to figure it out myself. 'slocate' is a compliment to 'find' not a replacement for, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would do it with find. something like:

```
find [startDir] -type d -name 'foobar'
```

this will find all directory named `foobar` under your `startDir` recursively.

for example:

```
kent$  pwd
/tmp

kent$  tree test
test
|-- f
|-- f1
|-- f2
|-- x
|   `-- test
|       |-- f1
|       |-- f2
|       `-- f3
`-- y

3 directories, 6 files

kent$  find /tmp -type d -name 'test'
/tmp/test
/tmp/test/x/test
```

Comment: Great alternative. Currently I have 950,000 files spanning multiple ZFS filesystems (within a single pool). slocate is faster but I'm using both. Serious house-cleaning going on.